# Simpler way to reconstitute a melted data frame back to the original

Tags: r, reshape2

How do I recreate a `data.frame` that I melted with `reshape2`?

**Reproducible example**

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
data(iris)
df  <- melt(iris, id.vars="Species")
head(df)
  Species     variable value
1  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1
2  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9
3  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7
4  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6
5  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0
6  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4
# Great, I'd like to get the original iris back
```

**What I've tried with `dcast`**

```
  dcast(df, Species~variable, value.var = "value")
    # should work but doesn't
```

**temporary solution**

```
# This works but clearly it shouldn't be this hard.
ddply(df, .(Species), function(x) {
    Species <- unique(x$Species)
    x$id <- 1:dim(x)[1]
    x$Species <- NULL
    dat <- unstack(x, value~variable)
    dat$Species <- Species
    return(dat)
    })
```

What am I missing? It's something obvious but I cannot figure out the answer. I may have even answered it for someone else here before. argh.

Comment: Based on your sample output, I think you may have meant to use `id.vars` not `measure.vars`.   Also, notice the typo in your call to melt which may be defaulting to the output you are seeing.

Comment: Yep, you caught my mistake. Thanks @RicardoSaporta

Comment: The problem is that your combination of variables *does not uniquely identify the row* (as you've multiple values for every combination. In this case, you will have to use `fun.aggregate`. Check `fun.aggregate` explanation from `?dcast`. Maybe an alternative is to use `unstack(df, value ~ variable)` and then `cbind` "Species" to this result..?

Comment: I was just about to make the same comment as @Arun!  Once you melt your data, is _melted_.  The metaphor is quite accurate.  You can recast it into another shape, but not the original, unless you tag each row with a source number before melting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *add some form of marker* to indicate which original row an item belongs to, then it is easy:

```
require(reshape2)
iris$rn <- seq_len(nrow(iris))
molten  <- melt(iris, id.vars = c("Species", "rn"))

# just a one-liner
dcast(molten, rn + Species ~ variable)
```

---

The difficulty you are encountering is that there is no way to identify which items go together.  Are the 1:5 rows in the molten set one row? or is it the 2:6 and the 1 is misplaced?  Melted data is in fact, melted :)